# Autumn Blaze Maple Tree 2 years old

Tags: trees

My Maple tree is losing all of it’s leaves and it’s only mid July. 
It was doing well, then all of a sudden the leaves turned brown pretty quick. I don’t see any bugs. It’s been pretty dry over the last few weeks, and I’ve watered it when I watered my flowers. (Not a lot of water, just for a minute or two) Did I not water it enough? Is it dying?  What can I do to save it? I’ve watered it a good bit over the last few days.

Comment: What part of the world are you in and is the tree in the ground or a pot?

Comment: A photo of the tree would help us to determine what may be going on with it.  Also - when was the last time your area received an inch or more of rain?

Answer (score 1):

You are underwatering your tree.  I would get a couple of 3" pvc pipes, 3' long.  Drill holes all down the length leaving a foot without holes.  Punch those pipes into the soil at the edge of the root ball, 2 feet deep.

Watering a few minutes isn't good for flowers, shrubs, lawns and especially not a tree.  We need to discuss how to water.  The key is DEEP watering and then allowing the soil to dry out before watering again.  If you have clay soils? even more important to know how long it takes to wet 4 to 6" deep.

I would get my hose out right now and shove it into the ground right into that root ball and soak that tree.  Do this every day for 4 days.

When the tree was planted was it in a burlap ball or a pot?  Was the burlap removed?  Has your tree been planted for 2 years or is it a 2 year old tree?  Very important to know.

How is your lawn doing?  Hand watering just never works.  Seriously never works unless you are able to stand and water for a good 1/4 hour.  The best way I've found to water is by a cheapo oscillating sprinkler.  Go away, forget it is going, finally turn it off.  Do you have automatic sprinklers and a timer?

Tell us more.  Go soak that tree.  Take a shovel and check the amount of time you hold that hose and how deep the water is able to get down in the soil.  4 to 6" is great.  You'll see what I mean.  Whatever plant needing that water will grow deeper roots to get at that moisture. Shallow rooted plants like weeds will die out in between waterings.

Your tree is in dire straights.  Stick the hose down into the soil, more than just one spot and soak the soil around that little tree.  You should see new growth in a week.